# Python C API - Call C function from embedded python (callback)

Tags: python, c++, callback

I have a .cpp file loading python file and calling a function. I have a logger class in the .cpp and I want to use it from .py file.

Example:

```
# python-file.py

def FunctionCalledFromC_API():
    log("some string")
    log("some error", error)
    log("some debug info", debug)
    # etc...
```

And the .cpp

```
// cpp-file.cpp

// Load python file, do stuff...
PyObject *args = PyTuple_New(0);
PyObject_CallObject(pFunctionCalledFromC_API, args);
Py_DECREF(args);
```

I want that the `log("some string")` function of the .py file calls my logger.log(...) function from the C++ application.

Comment: So, what is the problem you are having? What did you try?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I haven't found anything that can help me :( That's why I asked here. I don't know how to do that mixing C/C++ and Python. In C/C++ is easy, function pointers...

Comment: Check out the example for calling `printf` using [ctypes](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html). You will need to compile the `log` function into a dynamically loaded C library. You will probably also need to wrap `log` with `extern "C"` in order to use it from python.

Comment: Ok, but I won't compile ALL the callbacks into shared objects :S Too much callbacks! Should have I to compile all the application in a DLL and make another executable to run it?

Comment: Any C or C++ stuff that you want to access from python needs to go into a shared object. What you suggest is perhaps the easiest solution if you need to access a lot of different C functions in python -- put almost all of your C in a DLL, then create a very simple executable to run it.

Answer (score 0):

As Markku K. suggested, I made all my app a DLL and I'll try soon.

That's what I'll do (for people with the same question):

1. Make my app a single DLL
2. Make an executable to run it (obvious)
3. Make a Python file containing the functions (example: `logger.log()`). That functions should call the DLL's equivalent functions.
4. Do "trial&error" until it works ;)

**EDIT:**

After a lot of "trial&error", I've found a way to do it!

Using `boost::python` to [expose my API](http://boost.cppll.jp/HEAD/libs/python/doc/tutorial/doc/exposing_classes.html) and the standard Python API to load the .py file I made this work!
But I'll have to start the application with a python file importing the shared object and calling the main function :(

Anyway, Thanks Markku K. for your help!